# Que permisos necesita un usuario para restaurar un backup completo?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un usuario que se encarga de restaurar todos los días en ambiente test los backups que se obtienen de un ambiente productivo, planeo dar únicamente los privilegios necesarios para restaurarlos.

Actualmente luce así:

> 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, CREATE, DROP, PROCESS, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON . TO `backup_db`@`localhost`'
> 'GRANT BACKUP_ADMIN ON . TO `backup_db`@`localhost`'

Pero no restaura los stored procedures ni eventos, arroja el siguiente mensaje:

> Acces denied; you need (at least one of) the SYSTEM_USER privilege(s) for this operation.

Me pueden asesorar que permisos me faltan,por favor?

Comment: Hola, Carolina. De los resultados de búsqueda en Google cuando buscas *Acces denied; you need (at least one of) the SYSTEM_USER privilege(s) for this operation*, cuáles has intentado y cuáles no te han funcionado?

Comment: Hice pruebas al agregar el privilegio super de estas dos maneras: UPDATE mysql.user SET Super_Priv='Y' WHERE user='backup_db' AND host='localhost';

GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO 'backup_db'@'localhost';

Comment: Se soluciono al agregar el privilegio SYSTEM_USER, como lo mencionaba el mismo error